# Raw SQLite3 command in Django

Tags: sql, django, database, django-orm, sqlite3-python

I am trying to join 2 tables to display the orders that are matched to the username for the currently logged in user using SQLITE3, I have the SQL raw command written but I recieve the error: there is no such table Account. I have checked using the .tables sql command and the table is created and working. The program is also migrated without any errors but the Account table cant be found.

#### views.py

```py
from .models import Account, Order
from django.db import connection

def account(request):
    # Retrieve the currently logged in user
    user=request.session.get("user_id")
    if user is not None:
    
    
      # Retrieve the user's orders using a SQL join
      with connection.cursor() as cursor:
          cursor.execute('''
              SELECT a.Username, a.Email, o.Name, o.Surname, o.part
              FROM Account a
              INNER JOIN "Order" o ON a.Username = o.Username
              WHERE a.id = %s
          ''', [user])
          rows = cursor.fetchall()
          
          orders = []
          for row in rows:
              order = {
                  'Username': row[0],
                  'Email': row[1],
                  'Name': row[2],
                  'Surname': row[3],
                  'Part': row[4],
              }
              orders.append(order)
      print(orders)
      # Render the orders template with the orders data
      return render(request, 'orders.html', {'orders': orders})
    else:
      return redirect(reverse("home"))
```

The **Account** in line 11 is giving the error.

#### models.py

````py
class Account(models.Model):
  #Only one id can be created
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  #Uses in built CharField which means no special characters can be saved in the database, if special characters are part of the Username, the data will not be saved
  Username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  #Inbuilt EmailField, if email is not in correct format eg. TS_SHOP@gmail.com, then the value will not be saved
  Email= models.EmailField(max_length=20)
  
  Password=models.CharField(max_length=20)

#Table order which stores the customers order
class Order(models.Model):
  #primary key id
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  Surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  Address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  CreditCard= models.CharField(max_length=19)
  Username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  Email = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
  #validator only allows values shorter that 10 digits
  Zip = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(999999999)],null=True)
  City = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  Country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  part = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
  quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Django automatically derives the name of the database table from the name of your model class and the app that contains it ([source](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/table_name.html)). If you want to have a table named `account`, you have to configure it this way:

```py
class Account(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = "account"
```

So, I believe, you don't have a table call `Account` in your DB, its name is `<APP_NAME>_account`. You have to call it this way. Or you can just change the `Account` model like above.